# HTML How do I get the dropdown menu to be set in one place for all options?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, alignment

I'm trying to get the dropdown menu to appear in one place for all the options.

I want the dropdown menu to appear as it does for the 'Main 1' option (same position).
Currently, when I hover over the options, the menu appears in line for each 'Main' (Main 2, Main 3 etc) option, however I would like them all to all trigger the dropdown menu to appear exactly where 'Main 1' dropdown menu appears. I tried changing 'position: fixed' from 'position:relative' but the menu doesn't appear at all.

HTML:

```
<div class="sidebar_menu">
  <ul class="sidebar_menu_list">
    <li class="sidebar_menu_item">
      <a href=""><label class="sidebar_menu_label" for="sidebar_menu">Main 1</label>
      </a>
      <ul id="lp_test_pop_up">
        <div class="lp_test_popup_box">
          <div class="lp_category_item">
            <h3 id="lp_category_subheading"><a href="" id="">Sub-Item 1</a></h3>
            <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="lp_category_item">
            <h3 id="lp_category_subheading"><a href="" id="">Sub-Item 2</a></h3>
            <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="lp_category_item">
            <h3 id="lp_category_subheading"><a href="" id="">Sub-Item 3</a></h3>
            <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="lp_category_item">
            <h3 id="lp_category_subheading"><a href="" id="">Sub-Item 4</a></h3>
            <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="lp_category_item">
            <h3 id="lp_category_subheading"><a href="" id="">Sub-Item 5</a></h3>
            <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="lp_category_item">
            <h3 id="lp_category_subheading"><a href="" id="">Sub-Item 6</a></h3>
             <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </li>
     <li class="sidebar_menu_item">
      <a href=""><label class="sidebar_menu_label" for="sidebar_menu">Main 2</label>
      </a>
      <ul id="lp_test_pop_up">
        <div class="lp_test_popup_box">
          <div class="lp_category_item">
            <h3 id="lp_category_subheading"><a href="" id="">Sub-Item 1</a></h3>
            <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="lp_category_item">
            <h3 id="lp_category_subheading"><a href="" id="">Sub-Item 2</a></h3>
            <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="lp_category_item">
            <h3 id="lp_category_subheading"><a href="" id="">Sub-Item 3</a></h3>
            <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="lp_category_item">
            <h3 id="lp_category_subheading"><a href="" id="">Sub-Item 4</a></h3>
            <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="lp_category_item">
            <h3 id="lp_category_subheading"><a href="" id="">Sub-Item 5</a></h3>
            <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="lp_category_item">
            <h3 id="lp_category_subheading"><a href="" id="">Sub-Item 6</a></h3>
             <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </li>
     <li class="sidebar_menu_item">
      <a href=""><label class="sidebar_menu_label" for="sidebar_menu">Main 3</label>
      </a>
      <ul id="lp_test_pop_up">
        <div class="lp_test_popup_box">
          <div class="lp_category_item">
            <h3 id="lp_category_subheading"><a href="" id="">Sub-Item 1</a></h3>
            <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="lp_category_item">
            <h3 id="lp_category_subheading"><a href="" id="">Sub-Item 2</a></h3>
            <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="lp_category_item">
            <h3 id="lp_category_subheading"><a href="" id="">Sub-Item 3</a></h3>
            <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="lp_category_item">
            <h3 id="lp_category_subheading"><a href="" id="">Sub-Item 4</a></h3>
            <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="lp_category_item">
            <h3 id="lp_category_subheading"><a href="" id="">Sub-Item 5</a></h3>
            <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="lp_category_item">
            <h3 id="lp_category_subheading"><a href="" id="">Sub-Item 6</a></h3>
             <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </li>
     <li class="sidebar_menu_item">
      <a href=""><label class="sidebar_menu_label" for="sidebar_menu">Main 4</label>
      </a>
      <ul id="lp_test_pop_up">
        <div class="lp_test_popup_box">
          <div class="lp_category_item">
            <h3 id="lp_category_subheading"><a href="" id="">Sub-Item 1</a></h3>
            <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="lp_category_item">
            <h3 id="lp_category_subheading"><a href="" id="">Sub-Item 2</a></h3>
            <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="lp_category_item">
            <h3 id="lp_category_subheading"><a href="" id="">Sub-Item 3</a></h3>
            <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="lp_category_item">
            <h3 id="lp_category_subheading"><a href="" id="">Sub-Item 4</a></h3>
            <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="lp_category_item">
            <h3 id="lp_category_subheading"><a href="" id="">Sub-Item 5</a></h3>
            <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="lp_category_item">
            <h3 id="lp_category_subheading"><a href="" id="">Sub-Item 6</a></h3>
             <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </li>
     <li class="sidebar_menu_item">
      <a href=""><label class="sidebar_menu_label" for="sidebar_menu">Main 5</label>
      </a>
      <ul id="lp_test_pop_up">
        <div class="lp_test_popup_box">
          <div class="lp_category_item">
            <h3 id="lp_category_subheading"><a href="" id="">Sub-Item 1</a></h3>
            <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="lp_category_item">
            <h3 id="lp_category_subheading"><a href="" id="">Sub-Item 2</a></h3>
            <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="lp_category_item">
            <h3 id="lp_category_subheading"><a href="" id="">Sub-Item 3</a></h3>
            <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="lp_category_item">
            <h3 id="lp_category_subheading"><a href="" id="">Sub-Item 4</a></h3>
            <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="lp_category_item">
            <h3 id="lp_category_subheading"><a href="" id="">Sub-Item 5</a></h3>
            <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="lp_category_item">
            <h3 id="lp_category_subheading"><a href="" id="">Sub-Item 6</a></h3>
             <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </li>
     <li class="sidebar_menu_item">
      <a href=""><label class="sidebar_menu_label" for="sidebar_menu">Main 6</label>
      </a>
      <ul id="lp_test_pop_up">
        <div class="lp_test_popup_box">
          <div class="lp_category_item">
            <h3 id="lp_category_subheading"><a href="" id="">Sub-Item 1</a></h3>
            <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="lp_category_item">
            <h3 id="lp_category_subheading"><a href="" id="">Sub-Item 2</a></h3>
            <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="lp_category_item">
            <h3 id="lp_category_subheading"><a href="" id="">Sub-Item 3</a></h3>
            <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="lp_category_item">
            <h3 id="lp_category_subheading"><a href="" id="">Sub-Item 4</a></h3>
            <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="lp_category_item">
            <h3 id="lp_category_subheading"><a href="" id="">Sub-Item 5</a></h3>
            <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="lp_category_item">
            <h3 id="lp_category_subheading"><a href="" id="">Sub-Item 6</a></h3>
             <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.sidebar_menu_list  {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.sidebar_menu_item {
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  border-top: 1px solid #e4e8ea;
}

.sidebar_menu_item:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 12%);
  position: relative;
}

#lp_test_pop_up {
  transform: all 0.3s;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  left: 100%;
  top: -2%; 
}

.sidebar_menu_item:hover #lp_test_pop_up  {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: 9997;
}

.sidebar_menu  ul   li  a {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#lp_test_pop_up {
  width:634px;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 8px grey;
}

.sidebar_menu ul li ul ul {
  width: 134px;
  margin:15px 0px; 
  list-style-type:none;
  padding:0px;
}

.sidebar_menu ul li ul li {
  min-width: 250px;
  border: none;
}

label.sidebar_menu_label {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: black;
}

.lp_test_popup_box {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.lp_category_item {
  width: 33%;
  height: 125px;
}


#lp_category_subheading{
  margin:0px;
}

.lp_category_item{
  margin-bottom:20px;
}

.lp_category_item ul li{
  margin:2px 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a little liberty in redoing your HTML and I simplified your CSS, but I think have gotten what you're looking for. You want to have your menus unhide and display in the same place no matter which line item you hover over. In the CSS, I have set the positioning of the `target` div which I think you are having some trouble with. Hope this helps you some.

A better working example can be found on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-lnqufw?file=styles.css)

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

/* setting the positioning of the target here allows static display of the options */
.target {
  width: 350px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 8px grey;
}

.target ul {
   padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.target li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

li span {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* this is the important part here. the targets are the child of the hover element */
li span:hover + div.target {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 60px;
  left: 200px;
}

header {
  font-weight: bold;
}

header,
.row {
  display: flex; /* aligns all child elements (flex items) in a row */
}

.col {
  flex: 1; /* distributes space on the line equally among items */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>Main - Item 1</span>
    <div class="target">
      <section>
        <header>
          <div class="col">Sub-Item 1 A </div>
          <div class="col">Sub-Item 1 B</div>
          <div class="col">Sub-Item 1 C</div>
        </header>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
  </li>
  <li><span>Main - Item 2</span>
    <div class="target">
      <section>
        <header>
          <div class="col">Sub-Item 2 A</div>
          <div class="col">Sub-Item 2 B</div>
          <div class="col">Sub-Item 2 C</div>
        </header>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><span>Main - Item 3</span>
    <div class="target">
      <section>
        <header>
          <div class="col">Sub-Item 3 A</div>
          <div class="col">Sub-Item 3 B</div>
          <div class="col">Sub-Item 3 C</div>
        </header>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><span>Main - Item 4</span>
    <div class="target">
      <section>
        <header>
          <div class="col">Sub-Item 4 A</div>
          <div class="col">Sub-Item 4 B</div>
          <div class="col">Sub-Item 4 C</div>
        </header>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <ul>
              <li>choice 1</li>
              <li>choice 2</li>
              <li>choice 3</li>
              <li>choice 4</li>
              <li>choice 5</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but is there a simplier way of doing this without having to 'redoing' everything? Ideally I want to keep the structure of the HTML, or adjust a little.

Comment: I think your HTML is workable, but I'm thinking you might have to really rethink your CSS. That of course is where you're controlling the display of your elements on the page. I would say take what you can learn from this example and use it to modify your own work.